# Classes in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I have a complex model in Modelica. As I have lots of components in my model, I want to define classes and include some components inside the classes to reduce the complexity of the model. Since I couldn`t find online an example of the use of classes which are used in Modelica, could you give an idea how to define classes in Modelica?

The code is as follows;

```
model HD_3Kolben_bsp
    //Declaration(s)
    Real V_max = 0.000003;
    Real V_tod = 0.000002;
    Real N = 2800;
    replaceable package medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater( );
    Real opening_HP;
    Real opening_LP;
    constant Modelica.SIunits.AbsolutePressure patm = 1e5;
    Real opening_HP_2;
    Real opening_LP_2;
    Real opening_HP_3;
    Real opening_LP_3;
    constant Modelica.SIunits.Frequency freq = 46;
    //Component(s)
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Kolben1 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = false,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system (p_ambient = 101325);
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit1 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine1 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = freq,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = +Modelica.Constants.pi/2.01,
        startTime = 0);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume ClosedVolume1 (
        V = 0.000005/2,
        nPorts = 3,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_Swept_CV_1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_CV_HD_1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary Auslass (p = patm, redeclare package Medium = medium, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile1 (
        dp_nominal = 95,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_HP);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_ND_CV_1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear NDVentile1 (
        dp_nominal = 94.35,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_LP);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_Ein_ND (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary Einlass (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sensors.PositionSensor Position;
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sensors.PositionSensor Position2;
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear NDVentile2 (
        dp_nominal = 94.35,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_LP_2);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_ND_CV_2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile2 (
        dp_nominal = 95,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_HP_2);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_CV_HD_2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_Swept_CV_2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume ClosedVolume2 (
        V = 0.000005/2,
        nPorts = 3,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine2 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = freq,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = +Modelica.Constants.pi/2.01,
        startTime = 7/(3*freq));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit2 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Kolben2 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = false,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sensors.PositionSensor Position3;
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear NDVentile3 (
        dp_nominal = 94.35,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_LP_3);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_ND_CV_3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile3 (
        dp_nominal = 95,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_HP_3);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_CV_HD_3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_Swept_CV_3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume ClosedVolume3 (
        V = 0.000005/2,
        nPorts = 3,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine3 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = freq,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = +Modelica.Constants.pi/2.01,
        startTime = 14/(3*freq));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit3 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Kolben3 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = false,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary1 (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary2 (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.0055,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe4 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.0055,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe5 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.0055,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe6 (
        length = 0.24,
        diameter = 0.005,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_vb);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume2 (
        V = 3.13e-6,
        nPorts = 4,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice (diameter = 0.005, zeta = 0.98, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe7 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.005,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.VolumeFlowRate Volum1 (redeclare package Medium = medium);


equation
    if der(Position.s)>=0 then 
           opening_LP=1;  
           opening_HP=0; 
     else 
           opening_LP=0;
           opening_HP=1;
     end if; 
    if der(Position2.s)>=0 then 
           opening_LP_2=1;  
           opening_HP_2=0; 
     else 
           opening_LP_2=0;
           opening_HP_2=1;
     end if;
     if der(Position3.s)>=0 then 
           opening_LP_3=1;  
           opening_HP_3=0; 
     else 
           opening_LP_3=0;
           opening_HP_3=1;
     end if;
    //Connection(s)
    connect(Posit1.flange, Kolben1.flange);
    connect(Sine1.y, Posit1.s_ref);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_1.port_a, Kolben1.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_1.port_b, HDVentile1.port_a);
    connect(NDVentile1.port_b, pipe_ND_CV_1.port_a);
    connect(Einlass.ports[1], pipe_Ein_ND.port_a);
    connect(Posit1.flange, Position.flange);
    connect(Position2.flange, Posit2.flange);
    connect(NDVentile2.port_b, pipe_ND_CV_2.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile2.port_a, pipe_CV_HD_2.port_b);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_2.port_a, Kolben2.ports[1]);
    connect(Sine2.y, Posit2.s_ref);
    connect(Posit2.flange, Kolben2.flange);
    connect(Position3.flange, Posit3.flange);
    connect(NDVentile3.port_b, pipe_ND_CV_3.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile3.port_a, pipe_CV_HD_3.port_b);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_3.port_a, Kolben3.ports[1]);
    connect(Sine3.y, Posit3.s_ref);
    connect(Posit3.flange, Kolben3.flange);
    connect(boundary1.ports[1], pipe1.port_a);
    connect(boundary2.ports[1], pipe2.port_a);
    connect(pipe_Ein_ND.port_b, NDVentile1.port_a);
    connect(pipe1.port_b, NDVentile2.port_a);
    connect(pipe2.port_b, NDVentile3.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile1.port_b, pipe3.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile2.port_b, pipe4.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile3.port_b, pipe5.port_a);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_1.port_b, ClosedVolume1.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe_ND_CV_1.port_b, ClosedVolume1.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_1.port_a, ClosedVolume1.ports[3]);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_2.port_b, ClosedVolume2.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe_ND_CV_2.port_b, ClosedVolume2.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_2.port_a, ClosedVolume2.ports[3]);
    connect(pipe_Swept_CV_3.port_b, ClosedVolume3.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe_ND_CV_3.port_b, ClosedVolume3.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_3.port_a, ClosedVolume3.ports[3]);
    connect(pipe3.port_b, volume2.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe4.port_b, volume2.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe5.port_b, volume2.ports[3]);
    connect(volume2.ports[4], pipe6.port_a);
    connect(orifice.port_a, pipe6.port_b);
    connect(orifice.port_b, pipe7.port_a);
    connect(Volum1.port_b, Auslass.ports[1]);
    connect(Volum1.port_a, pipe7.port_b);
end  HD_3Kolben_bsp;
```

Comment: What do you mean by classes? would you like to divide your system in several subsystems?

Comment: Yes, I mean subsystems by classes.

Comment: Which tool are you using? Dymola?

Comment: I am using TwinBuilder 2020 R2.4

Comment: Could you add all the annotations in the code? If so I could propose  something.

Comment: How can I add the annotations?

Comment: In other tools they are normally part of the text and you have to deliberately exclude them; but I don't know about TwinBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using classes.
From the [doc][1]:

> The keyword class is used to define general classes (without any restrictions). It is identical to the keyword model. In most cases, it is recommended to use specialized classes as connector, model, block, package, record, function, type. "class" should be used to define ExternalObjects, and can be used for classes merely containing documentation and/or graphics.

In your example, e.g. the models `Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe`, `Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume` are reusable classes/models. If you have a reocurring set of pipes, volumes and valves, you may put them into one model to later reuse it.
[1]: https://doc.modelica.org/ModelicaReference%203.2.3/Resources/helpDymola/ModelicaReference_Classes.html#ModelicaReference.Classes